# How to merge two separate column data into one column in sqlite android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I store hour and minute in two separate column. i want to combine it like as hour:minute(9:15) and store timeunit(AM-PM) in separate column.how to do this can any one knows.hour and minute of String type.

Comment: Are you looking to store the combined hour and minute in the same or another SQLLite database table, or only on the webpage/app?

Comment: @brightmatrix in the same table

Answer (score 2):

Try to store the time in one column use one of the following types.

> [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_2_2) does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

- TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
- INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
  Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Its easier to store the time in one INTEGER column in milliseconds. And recreate it by `Date date = new Date(milliseconds)`. Then to get the hours and minutes from `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT (column1 || ":" || column2) AS expr1 FROM your_table;
```